# ProgressBar fluctuating because of downloading Multiple Files in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, webclient

I am implementing a windows form application in which we are taking url as input from multiline textbox and by using a loop we are downloading the files. In the download function I am implementing a webclient for downloading.

Using a loop creates too many Webclient requests .Now Since I have a single progressBar , it causes the progressbar to fluctuate. Here is an image of program.

[image]

I am looking for some method so that only one file is downloaded and causes other to pause for a while. This would cause progrressbar to work for one file only.

```
private void Download_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = "Starting Download ... Please Wait ...";


        string[] sep = new string[] { "\r\n" };
        string[] lines = textBox1.Text.Split(sep, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
        {
            download(lines[i]);
        }

    }


    private  void download(string song)
    {

        string name = song;

        song = query(song);
        using (webclient = new WebClient())
        {
            // ...statements
            using (client = new WebClient())
            {
                client.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(client_DownloadProgressChanged);
                client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
                client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(DOWN_URL + download_url), @dest + "\\" + name + ".mp3");
            }
        }



    }

    private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        count++;
        label1.Text = "Downloaded " + count.ToString() + " song(s)";
    }

    private void client_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        label1.Text = "Downloading";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you can [get size of file before downloading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079794/get-size-of-image-file-before-downloading-from-web) and use the `DownloadProgressChanged` to increment the already downloaded bytes

Comment: But this would cause me to run all WebClient services. I just want to run one at a time. There are multiple files being downloaded.

Comment: Can you afford the `DownloadFile` instead of the async version?

Comment: But, wouldn't it cause our UI to stop working.

Comment: I see; maybe this is the way to go: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3015445/113794

Comment: OK, This might help. I would give it a try.

Comment: You can still use the async version, but just prevent the user from downloading again, until the current download has completed (or caused an error).

Comment: Yes, I got it. I need to  start the download only after the event Download_completed is executed. BTW, Thanks or your reply.